# grunt replicate empty file structure

Tags: gruntjs

I would like to clone an existing file structure, without copying the files, during a grunt task. The new structure should be empty in the beginning and will be filled with processed data from the already existing file structure.

I've checked grunt-contrib-copy but there seems to be no filter for copying directories only.

Answer (score 0):

This is true, place a `.keep` file in each (or lowest-level) directory and run grunt-contrib-copy and it will replicate your structure.

Updating this to cover the comments:

There is *currently* no option in grunt-contrib-copy or grunt-init to copy the structure *only*.

If however, you put aside the option of starting from 0, you could simply allow the pre-processed data to fill the structure, and pass a `newer:` to your copy task to only overwrite files that are older than those present.

If you absolutely *need* those folders to be empty, your best bet is to set up a boilerplate for yourself. I wish I could stumble on something better for this.

Comment: Yes. You want to just replicate the folder structure and _not_ copy any actual files? Or would you just want to copy certain files like `/*.{html,css}`?

Comment: Just the empty file structure

Comment: [Grunt member](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-init/issues/41) recommends either [cpr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cpr) or grunt.file.mkdir. I'd take a longer look at cpr if you need to copy the structure repeatedly. You could probably create a sloppy workaround with grunt-contrib-copy and grunt-contrib-clean, but that's a lot of work to duplicate the structure.

Comment: Thx suzunakes! Good reference